# PostGIS ST_Intersects or ST_Within for Point in Boundary

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

When I query with `ST_Intersects` or `ST_Within` I get the same result. I want to know which one to use for performance wise? **Note:** For points, there is no difference.

**Using ST_Within:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT id, name,short_name,type FROM locations WHERE ST_Within('SRID=4326;POINT(9.1011853 49.5994825)',bounding_polygon)
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
"Index Scan using locations_bounding_polygon_idx on locations  (cost=0.29..19727.17 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.326..1.389 rows=8 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (bounding_polygon ~ '0101000020E610000001AC448FCE3322401D03B2D7BBCC4840'::geometry)"
"  Filter: st_within('0101000020E610000001AC448FCE3322401D03B2D7BBCC4840'::geometry, bounding_polygon)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 18"
"Planning Time: 0.126 ms"
"Execution Time: 1.405 ms"
```

**Using ST_Intersects:**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT id, name,short_name,type FROM locations WHERE ST_Intersects(bounding_polygon, 'SRID=4326;POINT(9.1011853 49.5994825)')
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
"Index Scan using locations_bounding_polygon_idx on locations  (cost=0.29..33.30 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.270..1.102 rows=8 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (bounding_polygon && '0101000020E610000001AC448FCE3322401D03B2D7BBCC4840'::geometry)"
"  Filter: st_intersects(bounding_polygon, '0101000020E610000001AC448FCE3322401D03B2D7BBCC4840'::geometry)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 18"
"Planning Time: 0.231 ms"
"Execution Time: 1.116 ms"
```

**ST_Intersects:** https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html If a geometry or geography shares any portion of space then they intersect.

**ST_Within:** https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html Returns TRUE if geometry A is completely inside geometry B

Comment: `ST_Intersects` bools out earlier than other relationship functions. If in doubt, this is trivial to test. Bonus performance: `ST_Subdivide` your polygons.

Comment: I have to add: this is true for Point in Polygon, but not necesarily for other combinations; `ST_Within` checks for bbox *containment* (`~`), which *may* have a significant impact on index driven exclusion compared to bbox *intersection* (`&&`) used by `ST_Intersects` - despite the computationally more expensive *true containment* check.